# regex not closing span

Tags: php, regex

I'm a bit at a loss. The below regex works as expected:

```
$src_data = preg_replace("/&quot;(.+?)&quot;/", "<span class=\"src_att\">$0</span>", $src_data);
$src_data = preg_replace("/'(.+?)'/", "<span class=\"src_att\">$0</span>", $src_data);
```

However, this one fails to close the span:

```
$src_data = preg_replace("/\/\/(.+?)\n/", "<span class=\"src_com\">$0</span>", $src_data);
```

Sure enough it's something trivia but I fail to see the error. Any help appreciated, thanks.

EDIT:

$src_data may be anything, e.g. a single line or multiple lines. The below is an example with single quotes - awhich works as expected:

```
$ds_type = array ('Bytes', 'KiB', 'MiB', 'GiB', 'TiB');
```

Albeit, trying to match a comment fails to add the closing span:

```
//** this is just a comment
```

The output is renderd fine, but obviously the mark-up is invalid due to the missing span.

Comment: Can you add some examples of $src_data

Comment: The `</span>` will be on the next line, since the newline is at the end of `$0`.

Comment: Maybe you should use `$` instead of `\n`, along with the `m` option that makes it match end of line instead of end of string.

Comment: The </span> is exactly where it's supposed to be with the first two regex. There's no </span> nowhere for the problem child. Tried $ and /m and it fails, too.

Comment: It works here: http://ideone.com/KOK6v8 As I said above, `</span>` is on the next line. It will only fail if the comment is at the end of the string, with no newline after it.

Answer (score 0):

Hate doing this, but since it's fixed I'll answer myself.

```
$src_data = preg_replace("/\/\/(.*?)$/m", "<span class=\"src_com\">$0</span>", $src_data);
```

Changing `.*+?` to `.*?` in conjunction with `$/m` was all it took. Did I mention trivia... Thanks all around.